# I need help with the algebraic portion of this complex trig question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let $z = 2 e^{10 \pi i/21} $ and $w = e^{\pi i/7}$. Then if $[(z-w)^6  = r e^{i\theta}]$where $r \geq 0$ and $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$, what is the ordered pair $(r, \theta)$?

I have the starting idea of drawing it out on the graph table. Currently, I need some help with the algebraic portion of the problem.

Comment: Half of that was answered already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899167/let-z-2-e10-pi-i-21-and-w-e-pi-i-7-then-what-is-zw6-the) in response to your previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(z-w)^6  = r e^{i\theta}$$
$$|(z-w)^6 |= |r e^{i\theta}|$$
$$|(z-w) |^6= r $$
$$z -w= e^{\pi i/7}(2e^{\pi i/3}-1)$$
$$|z -w|= |e^{\pi i/7}(2e^{\pi i/3}-1)|=|e^{\pi i/7}|\cdot|(2e^{\pi i/3}-1)|$$
$$|z -w|=1\cdot|(2e^{\pi i/3}-1)|=\sqrt{3}$$
$$r=|(z-w) |^6=27 $$

---

$$Arg(z-w)^6=6\cdot Arg(z-w)$$
$$z-w=e^{\pi i/7}(2e^{\pi i/3}-1)$$
$$arg(z-w)=\frac{9\pi}{14}$$

Comment: wait so what would theta be?

Comment: $$\theta =27\pi/7=6\pi/7 $$

Comment: @ james I am kind of confused on what r would be equal to. Can you explain to me?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

We have that

- $r=|z-w|^6$
- $Arg((z-w)^6)=6\cdot Arg(z-w)$
- $Arg(z_1z_2)=Arg(z_1)+Arg(z_2)$

and

$$z -w= 2 e^{10 \pi i/21} - e^{\pi i/7}=e^{\pi i/7}(2e^{\pi i/3}-1)$$